# Eval safety in python, string pulled from JSON

Tags: python, security, networking, eval, twisted

I'm wracking my brain trying to find a way to exploit this setup. My concept is this: my twisted server receives messages (via `LineReceiver`). The messages are base64 JSON, which SHOULD contain a single dictionary. The dictionary has a `"INSTRUCTION"` key which indicates what sort of client action the server should be processing.

At this portion of the program, `line` is a base64 string received over the network.

```
def Decode(line):
    return json.loads(base64.b64decode(line))
```

And the interpretation (inside a twisted `Protocol` object)

```
def lineReceived(self, line):
    instruction = Decode(line)  #dict
    if instruction and "INSTRUCTION" in instruction:
        if instruction["INSTRUCTION"] in ("register", "join", "create", 
         "list", "passturn", "impmove", "warpmove","laserattack",
         "torpattack", "mine", "data", "status"):
            cmdstring = instruction["INSTRUCTION"] + "(self)"
            eval(cmdstring)
```

Why I think it's safe:

- eval will only run if I get a plain string as the value.
- JSON can't pack complex objecst, only python basics. An attacker shouldn't have `__str__` access to what I receive, right?
- I'm using eval to provide a less readable but much more compact replacement for a dozen `if instruction["INSTRUCTION"] == "functionA": functionA(self)` lines. I'm just running eval to choose a function from a specific list.

Is this safe? Is this considered acceptable style or form? Is this block of code robust enough for a multiplayer game, since the client cannot be trusted? (Validation that the instruction follows the game rules is later, here I want to protect my server from destructive tinkering.)

Is there a better way to do what I'm attempting (remote execution of a function, I suppose) that is more standard / safe?

Comment: Why are you base64-encoding JSON? That'll only expand the payload size, without any gain in transferability..

Comment: look how an [irc bot supports executing command](http://www.habnabit.org/twistedex.html)

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a terrible protocol.  Is this something you've designed or something you just have to cope with?  If you have any control over it, you should consider using AMP http://amp-protocol.net or something similar.

Answer (score 4):

You'd be better of using `getattr()`:

```
if instruction and "INSTRUCTION" in instruction:
    instr_callable = getattr(self, 'do_' + instruction['INSTRUCTION'], None)
    if instr_callable is not None:
        instr_callable()
```

where `do_` is prefixed to the instruction name to ensure that only allowed methods are called through this method.

If your instruction functions live in the global namespace, use `globals()` instead, and use it as a mapping:

```
if instruction and "INSTRUCTION" in instruction:
    instr_callable = globals().get('do_' + instruction['INSTRUCTION'], None)
    if instr_callable is not None:
        instr_callable(self)
```

However, you'd then be better of putting those callables in an explicit mapping:

```
instr_callables = dict(
    register=register,
    join=join,
    ...
)

if instruction and "INSTRUCTION" in instruction:
    instr_callable = instr_callables.get(instruction['INSTRUCTION'], None)
    if instr_callable is not None:
        instr_callable(self)
```

`eval()` is rarely, if ever, needed to look up arbitrary objects in python namespaces.

Comment: Bah, beat me to it.  I called mine "instruction_name/instruction_fn", though, to prevent clobbering `callable` (not that anyone ever uses it.)

Comment: @DSM: Better keep the SO proverbial nose clean and not shadow callable.

Comment: a prefix such as `'do_'` could be used: `getattr(self, 'do_'+...)`. If functions are global; a module object can be used instead of `self`, no need to duplicate names